# Booking in MySQL and Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, date-range

I have problem with listing reservation who has more than one reservation and I don't what to this apartment be listed.

```
$show_apartments = DB::table('apartments')
  ->join('reservation', 'unos_id', '=', 'reservation.id_nekretnina')
  ->select('unos_id as link', 'title', 'description', 'picture', 'slug',               'max_person','reservation.dolazak','reservation.odlazak')
  ->whereNotBetween('dolazak', [$in_sql, $out_sql]) 
  // this is date check in and check out in search field
  ->whereNotBetween('odlazak', [$in_sql, $out_sql]) 
  // this is date check in and check out in search field
  ->get();
```

All apartments list very well but problem is when some apartment is more than one different date reservation then apartment is listed but I want only if apartment is in this range is free. I tray 50h and didn't look the solution.

When someone help me I will put this in stored procedure.

I know what is problem but I don't know to write code for this.
(if in some ID_APARTMENT has this date range then don't show me this Apartment, rest yes)

Answer (score 1):

I found answer.
Need to use 
->whereBetween - then in other query use 
->whereNotIn result from first query.

It's easy now but i lost one week for this. ;)